# Indefinite Integral not Solving

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I'm tring to solve the Indefinite Integral of the function:

```
fx[zf_] := 
 Log[1.9607843137254901` (0.42` + 
     0.09000000000000008` (0.11030501767281171` \
E^(-0.06294157608695654` (-0.38964705882352935` + zf)^2) + 
        1/2 Erfc[0.250881597744746` (-0.38964705882352935` + zf)] - 
        1/2 E^(0.0981` zf) (1.0382243764705883` + 0.0981` zf) Erfc[
          0.250881597744746` (0.38964705882352935` + zf)]))]
```

When I try to solve the integral:

```
Integrate[fx[zf], zf]
```

Mathematica do not give any result. The only assumptyon needed is that zf must be >= 0.

Comment: There probably isn't a 'nice' closed form antiderivative. It's too complicated for Mathematica. You can get a series approximation though if that helps. Here's the first 5 terms of the series: `Series[Integrate[fx[zf], zf], {zf, 0, 5}]` giving `-0.15174 zf - 0.00803721 zf^2 + 0.00048911 zf^3 + 0.0000386184 zf^4 - 
 4.66256*10^-6 zf^5`

Comment: I also attempted it with Rubi, https://rulebasedintegration.org but the result was extremely complicated and still contained unresolved integrals.

Comment: Sometimes exact solvers like `Integrate` do not work well with floating-point coefficients. Round-off error can be a problem.  In this case, it seems there's no known antiderivative.  `NDSolve` could compute a numerical antiderivative over a finite domain, if that's of interest.